# npm quit all parallel running processes

Tags: npm

i am new to the topic of npm and i try to build automatic test-process with npm scripts. The only issue i have is that i don't see any possibility to quit all parallel running processes when one special task ends

My Process:

1. build application
2. start local web server
3. start json-api mock server
4. execute test

my script call in package.json looks like this:

```
"test": "npm run build-dev 
   && parallelshell \"npm run start-testproxy\" 
                     \"npm run json-server\" 
                     \"npm run e2e\""
```

**How can i exit all other processes after "e2e" finished?**

( the process remains running, if i cancel it with ctrl+c on windows, 'parallelshell' will kill all sub processes, but i dont know how to realize that with a npm script )

thanks a lot